# Codeship doesn't deploy to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, continuous-integration, codeship

I'm using Codeship to deploy my NodeJS app (hosted on bitbucket) to Heroku.

In Codeship I chose heroku and added my Heroku API Key and also the name of the app on Heroku. But when I push to bitbucket and look at the log in codeship, there's no sign of deploying to Heroku and it finishes the job successfully in green zone after doing `npm install`

Is there any other script I have to add? Is there any command in CLI I have to run?

---

**Answer:**

Actually, as **mlocher** mentioned in his comment, I had to define specifically the branch that triggers the deployment pipeline. (in my case `master`)

Comment: Ahoy could you check that the branch you run the build for matches the branch defined in the deplyoment configuration exactly? I.e. no additional whitespace, same capitalization, ...

If the deployment is still not run, could you get in touch via support@codeship.com?

Comment: @mlocher: it works now, I did the same thing before with another project and didn't specify the name and it worked !! but now that I specified it works , thanks

Comment: Great! Feel free to reach out if any other Codeship related questions come up, were always happy to help. And if you could update the question, that would be highly appreciated!